# Sencha touch issue in calling json webservice

Tags: json, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I am trying to call a json web service which is deployed in localhost(Tomcat) from sencha touch, but i am getting bad request response and when i remove content-type i receive unsupported type. Please help providing me the exact code for consuming json service from sencha touch.

Here is the code,

```
 Ext.Ajax.request({
        url:'../service/login.json',
        headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
        method:'POST',
        params:{email:Ext.getCmp('login_field').getItems().items[0].getValue(),password:Ext.getCmp('login_field').getItems().items[1].getValue()},
        success:function(res,req){
            alert(res.reponseText);
            var data  = Ext.decode(res.responseText);
            if(data.responseMessage){
                Ext.getCmp('login_field').getItems().items[0].reset();
                Ext.getCmp('login_field').getItems().items[1].reset();
                if(!Ext.getCmp('MainPanel')){
                    Ext.Viewport.add({xtype: 'MainPanel'});
                }
                Ext.getCmp('MainPanel').show({type:'slideIn',direction:'left'});
                Ext.getCmp('LoginPanel').hide();

            }
    else{

            Ext.Msg.alert('Health Track','Invalid Login');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I am using in my app. Be sure to use the network inspector in your browser or tool of choice to see if the call is being processed.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: http://www.example.com,
    withCredentials: false,
    useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
    params: {
        login: foo@bar.baz,
        password: *******
    },

    callback: this.handleLoginCallback,
    scope:this
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your service consumes & produces. You have to specify 'Content-Type': 'application/json' if you want to hit correct end point(which accepts json). If you want to get JSOn response you have to send "Accept" header also otherwise you will get default type (which is xml in most of the cases). Alternatively you can use hacks like passing "_type=json" in url or appending ".json" in the url to get json response back.